# Implementing Sales Tracking for Products Listed on External Websites via Script

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, tracking

I have a platform where users create ads, and these ads are listed on other sites through a script tag embedded in their websites. When users click on these ads, they are redirected to product sites. I need advice on implementing a sales tracking system to retrieve product prices and confirm sales when users are redirected from the ad to the product site. What approaches and methods can be employed to achieve effective sales tracking in this scenario?

Problem is that I cant target any tag , class or id because I don't know about the product site structure.